# python how to update json list if condition matches

Tags: python, json, list

I'm sorry about the code in spanish, but besides that, you should be able to understand it's structure, i am using Python 3.3.2 and getting a problem here.

```
leyendoestadisticas = open("listas\Estadisticas.txt", "r")
bufferestadisticas = leyendoestadisticas.read()
leyendoestadisticas.close()
if not '"'+user.name+'"' in bufferestadisticas: #If name is not found, do this
  escribiendoestadisticas = open("listas\Estadisticas.txt", 'a')
  escribiendoestadisticas.write(json.dumps([user.name, palabrasdelafrase, letrasdelafrase,
                                            "1", user.nameColor, user.fontColor, user.fontFace, user.fontSize, message.body, room.name])+"\n")
  escribiendoestadisticas.close()
else: #If name is found...
  data = []
  with open('listas\Estadisticas.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
      data_line = json.loads(line)
      if data_line[0] == user.name: #if name matches...
        if data_line[9] == room.name: #And room also, then update info.
          data_line[1] = int(data_line[1])+int(palabrasdelafrase)
          data_line[2] = int(data_line[2])+int(letrasdelafrase)
          data_line[3] = int(data_line[3])+1
          data_line[4] = user.nameColor
          data_line[5] = user.fontColor
          data_line[6] = user.fontFace
          data_line[7] = user.fontSize
          data_line[8] = message.body
          data_line[9] = room.name
        else: #but if name is found and room doesn't matches. #PROBLEM HERE
          escribiendoestadisticas = open("listas\Estadisticas.txt", 'a')
          escribiendoestadisticas.write(json.dumps([user.name, palabrasdelafrase, letrasdelafrase,
                                                  "1", user.nameColor, user.fontColor, user.fontFace, user.fontSize, message.body, room.name])+"\n")
          escribiendoestadisticas.close()
      data.append(data_line)
      break
    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(["%s\n" % json.dumps(i) for i in data])
    f.truncate()
```

It's purpose is to add an user.name and update it's info as long as the property 9 of the line matches. If not matches, then add a new line to the list with the same user.name but the new value for property 9.

It works perfect if the property 9 matches, however if it doesn't, what it's doing is to overriding the existing value of that user.name and starting counting the properties in [1], [2] and [3] from scratch.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:** Updating with the information from an answer:

```
else: 
  data = []
  with open('listas\Estadisticas.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
  for line in lines:
    data_line = json.loads(line)
    if data_line[0] == user.name: 
      if data_line[9] == room.name:
        data_line[1] = int(data_line[1])+int(palabrasdelafrase)
        data_line[2] = int(data_line[2])+int(letrasdelafrase)
        data_line[3] = int(data_line[3])+1
        data_line[4] = user.nameColor
        data_line[5] = user.fontColor
        data_line[6] = user.fontFace
        data_line[7] = user.fontSize
        data_line[8] = message.body
        data_line[9] = room.name
      data.append(data_line)
  f.seek(0)
  f.writelines(["%s\n" % json.dumps(i) for i in data])
  f.truncate()
  for line in lines: 
    data_line = json.loads(line)
    if data_line[0] == user.name: 
      if not data_line[9] == room.name:
        escribiendoestadisticas = open("listas\Estadisticas.txt", 'a')
        escribiendoestadisticas.write(json.dumps([user.name, palabrasdelafrase, letrasdelafrase,
                                                "1", user.nameColor, user.fontColor, user.fontFace, user.fontSize, message.body, room.name])+"\n")
        escribiendoestadisticas.close()
```

But now i'm getting error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
Completely lost.

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Comment: Do you want to append to the file on the fly, or rewrite the whole thing at the end? You surely can't want to do _both_.

Comment: I'm not sure if the innermost `else` condition makes sense. If a user name can be in the file multiple times with different room numbers, you probably want to search the whole file until you find a matching room, rather than breaking after finding the first matching name.

Comment: Yeah noticed now, it was suppose to be only for one room, so only 1 user with the same name in the whole list. However now i am upgrading it to allow several same user.names just with a different room in the value[9] and... i'm lost.

Comment: @abarnert i would like to append the file on the fly.

Comment: @Saelyth: If you want to append on the fly, don't rewrite at the end. But… are you sure you want that? There are some major downsides to that. For example, you can't overwrite/replace a row that way. Also, you may or may not (arbitrarily) see the newly-appended rows in your for loop, so your algorithm has to work properly either way.

Comment: The reason the new version gets that I/O error is that you're now immediately closing `f`, as cjrh suggested, but you're still trying to call things like `f.seek(0)` on it anyway. You can't do that. If you want to reopen the file, you can. But the whole point of his answer was to not touch the file at all in the middle of processing: read it all in, process it, then write it all out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are modifying the file while still reading from it.  Load the file completely first, and let the context handler close the file:

```
else: #Si está, suma datos
  data = []
  with open('listas\Estadisticas.txt', 'r+') as f:
      lines = f.readlines()

  for line in lines:
    data_line = json.loads(line)
    if data_line[0] == user.name: #if name is found...
      if data_line[9] == room.name: #And room also, then update info.
        data_line[1] = int(data_line[1])+int(palabrasdelafrase)
        [etc]
```

As other people have indicated in comments, you probably want to search the whole file for `user.name`, not just line-by-line anyway.

Also, as @abarnert points out, rather just modify `data` in your loops, and then write out the complete set of information at the end.

---

Several general comments:

- Your code doesn't handle the case when `data_line` contains less than 10 items.  Your program will crash if this happens.
- You would be much better off using `json` to save an entire `dict` to file.  This way, when you load the `dict`, you can immediately check for, and access the `user.name`.  I am suggesting you make `user.name` the key of the dictionary.

It might look something like this (EDIT: saw you wanted unique combos of user.name and room.name):

```
with open('listas\Estadisticas.json', 'rb') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

key = (user.name, room.name)

if key in data:
    data[key]['nameColor'] = user.nameColor
    [...etc...]
else:
    # I am not sure what details are different
    data[key] = {} # New sub-dict
    data[key]['nameColor'] = user.nameColor
    [...etc...]

with open('listas\Estadisticas.json', 'wb') as f:
    json.dump(f, data)
```

- *Names can change*.  This is why databases usually use keys that are not the names of people, or names of rooms.  I would suggest that you assign names of things to something else abstract, like numbers, and then look up the names when required for display.  If a user's name is enterend incorrectly initially, and later they want to correct the spelling of their name, you will have a hard time explaining to them that you can't because it will mean all their data will be lost...

Comment: Although i understand what you two meant to say, i'm afraid i'm too noob to search in the whole file for the username without the line by line method of json module. So i was just trying to do a workaround.

Comment: Never used dicts before, but if i am understanding this code right, where do you say the roomname is the value number 9 in the list?

Comment: So, my `data`is not a list.  It is a dictionary with a key.  The key is a tuple with two entries: `user.name` and `room.name`.  If a user hasn't yet been assigned a room, then the tuple just looks like `(user.name, "")`.  Setting it up this way makes finding users easy and prevents duplicates of the combination of user and room.

Comment: At the place where I say `if key in data`, I am checking to see whether the combination of user and room has already been entered.  If that check fails, then it means that that combination has not been entered (in which case I guess you want to add it?

Comment: yeah i get that but where do you say to the python program wich value is the room.name, if [3] or [9]? Or i don't need to specifically set that and the program will check if user.name matches with the room.name in [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8] AND [9]? if that's the case i don't think it would work since i guess i would get wrong information if my chance value in [8] is the same room.name as should be in [9] but being [9] different in that line.

Comment: Ah ok.  I am suggesting that you *no longer* use fixed positions like [3] or [9] to store things, but rather use names for each of the parts of data.

Comment: I was reading info from that link, and it just comes to my mind... my actual database already has 1600 items... if i want to convert it to dictionaries the amount of data to change would be ridiculous insane :\